# Bought an xcode project for an app already in the apple store. Do I need to change the Bundle Identifier and create a new App Id for it?

Tags: xcode, app-store

New to XCode programming and Apple store uploading protocol.  Like the title states, do I need to change the bundle Identifier and create a new AppId for the app whose code I bought from the original developer, who had already had it approved in the Apple Store (since I intend on modifying the code "slightly" and selling the updated app under my own company's name also in the apple store)?

I suppose I could do so and perhaps get rejected, but I'd like to avoid that if possible and do it the correct way first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to publish an app under your account you need to create a new App ID and a new Distribution Profile under your account.